# PHP preg_match with html tags

Tags: php, string, preg-match

I'm trying to exctract some string inside a pattern.

the string is

```
<br /><br /><br />Text i want here
<br /></div>
```

i want the: "Text i want here"

My attemp was

```
preg_match('!<br /><br /><br />(.*?)<br /></div>!xi', $homepage, $matches);
```

But failed.

**I use the x because may between 
 they have some white space or \n.

```
<br />
<br />
<br />Text u want here
<br /></div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please refrain from parsing HTML with RegEx as it will [drive you į̷̷͚̤̤̖̱̦͍͗̒̈̅̄̎n̨͖͓̹͍͎͔͈̝̲͐ͪ͛̃̄͛ṣ̷̵̞̦ͤ̅̉̋ͪ͑͛ͥ͜a̷̘͖̮͔͎͛̇̏̒͆̆͘n͇͔̤̼͙̩͖̭ͤ͋̉͌͟eͥ͒͆ͧͨ̽͞҉̹͍̳̻͢](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use an [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) instead.

Answer (score 1):

use `strip_tags("<br /><br /><br />Text i want here<br /></div>")`.

[`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) will strip all HTML and PHP tags from a string.

Comment: If you want to stick to regular expressions though you would need to take into consideration that your original string is multiline and that is why it's not matched. You should try using the `s` modifier and allow for matching newline characters between tags (e.g. `!<br />.*<br />.*<br />(.*)<br />.*</div>!s` will do)

Comment: @Muthu Kumaran This is a full html doc so i cant just strip the tags because i want a specific part on the whole html :).

Comment: @ Michal Trojanowski  I try that but still nothing. :/